# Script to fill out form executes faster than onchange() can show options for form

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using a Javascript bookmarklet to automatically fill out a form on a page. Some of the options given are drop down selections, which reveal different options depending on what is selected using onchange(). I have code similar to this:

```
/* Gets first drop down and sets value to first in list */
var dropDown1 = document.getElementById("dropDown1Name");
dropDown1.value = "option1InDropDown";
dropDown1.onchange();

/* Sets value of second drop down to option that is available when first option in first drop down is selected */
var dropDown2 = document.getElementById("dropDown2Name");
dropDown2.value = "optionRevealedByDropDown1Change";
```

However this doesn't work because the onchange() doesn't populate the second drop down by the time I set it to the value. By the time the script finishes executing, there is no value set in dropDown2. I've tried several methods to make the code "wait" but I haven't been able to find a correct solution. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can't always trigger the 'change' event like that, try using [element.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) instead.

Comment: I made a fiddle showing how you can do it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GGG_KILLER/epm7wrk7/1/)

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful in learning how to trigger events. I still have my issue though, since it seems like the second drop down value tries to set before the values are "set up" from the event.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Stubb0rn's answer then, you'll have to watch for when the `<option>`s inside the `<select>` change instead of immediately doing it.

Comment: @user1527216 have you reviewed my answer? Simply using `input` event rather than `change` event, should take care of that lag issue. `input` is instant whille `change` doesn't act until the `event.target` is no longer focused on (i.e. `blur` event). So using `change` makes you dependent on what the user does next.

Comment: The problems you will face are: (1) when the second `<select>` options are set, `onchange` and `oninput` events don't fire when the HTML is changed or options are added to a `<select>` element (2) listening to HTML changes requires newer browsers and MutationObserver. Can you tell us the page with the form? It would help for us to know how the second dropdown is populated. Perhaps a custom even is fired and can be listened to.

Comment: Might be inefficient, but you could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to check for changes on the second `<select>` after triggering the `change` event on the first `<select>` then remove the interval with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) after processing the second `<select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already pointed out in comments one part of the problem is incorrect triggering of `change` event. Another part of the problem might be the fact that options for second dropdown might be populated only after receiving result of some async action (for example using XMLHttpRequest). In this case even if `change` event is triggered correctly, your code still needs to wait for dropdown to get populated before setting it's value. One approach might be based on regular checks if dropdown is populated with values (e.g. using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`). More elegant approach could use `MutationObserver` to wait for dropdown to get populated with values. Take a look at this snippet:

```js
var sel1 = document.querySelector('#sel'),
  sel2 = document.querySelector('#sel2');

// Onchange code
sel1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  sel2.disabled = false;
  // emulate async request for dropdown options
  setTimeout(function populateSecondSelect() {
    ['', 'dynamic1', 'dynamic2'].forEach(function(val) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.setAttribute('value', val);
      opt.textContent = val || '-';
      sel2.appendChild(opt);
    });
  }, 2000);
});

// Code to trigger events (based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/2671392)
function triggerEvent(type, element) {
  var event; // The custom event that will be created

  if (!!window.Event) {
    event = new Event(type);
  } else if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent(type, true, true);
  } else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = type;
  }

  event.eventName = type;

  if (document.createEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
  }
}

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  sel1.value = sel1.value === '1' ? '2' : '1';
  // trigger change event
  triggerEvent('change', sel1);
  // set MutationObserver for second dropdown
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    sel2.value = 'dynamic2';
    observer.disconnect();
  });
  // only observe changes in the list of children
  var observerConfig = {
    childList: true
  };
  observer.observe(sel2, observerConfig);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Select values" />
  <select id="sel">
    <option value="" selected>-</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel2" disabled>
  </select>
</div>
```

But be aware that `MutationObserver` is not available in older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the first `<select>` with the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/InputEvent) event which is like `change` except it triggers immediately. In order to sync the first `<select>`'s value to the second `<select>`'s option and value use [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property in the event handler.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var s1 = document.getElementById('s1');
var s2 = document.getElementById('s2');

s1.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var idx = this.selectedIndex;
  var data = idx.value;
  s2.selectedIndex = idx;

}, false);
```

```css
label {
  margin-left: 6ex;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Binding Input Event</legend>
  <select id='s1'>
    <option>---</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
  </select>

  <select id='s2'>
    <option>---</option>
    <option value='A'>A</option>
    <option value='B'>B</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
  </select>


</fieldset>
```